# Can you detect no finger enrolled with react-native-keychain

Tags: react-native, react-native-keychain

Looking for an error message similar to 
"could not start because Fingerprint Scanner has no enrolled fingers".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Stack Overflow is meant to answer questions about code. You have not provided any code - I would say that your question could be answered by reading the documentation. I have never personally used `react-native-keychain` - instead, I use `react-native-sensitive-info` for its superior support of Android. If you find that `react-native-keychain` does not have such a feature, `react-native-sensitive-info` does throw an error like that when no fingers are enrolled.

Comment: Thanks, for your response. Looks like i already knew the answer since a read the documentation. Will check out react-native-sensitive-info.